# Android Intent Activity Callback

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android module that basically consists of a custom View third parties can just drop into any of their activities.
This module includes a configuration activity (based on PreferenceActivity).

Given that you can't start an activity from a View, the module calls 'openConfig(Intent intent)' on the activity it is displayed in. This activity acts as a delegate for the module.

That works fine thus far (though I'd really like the module to handle everything internally, no delegate methods required, but I reckon that just isn't possible).
However, I need some sort of callback from the preference activity to the module, so that the module will get notified when the settings have been changed.

I was thinking of just adding the module's main class as a delegate to the preference activity;

```
ConfigActivity a = new ConfigActivity();
a.testVar = "testtest";
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), a.getClass());
delegate.handleConfigAction(intent); //
```

However, this test with just a simple String (instead of an interface) showed, that the String wouldn't get set after the activity has been started.

Second thought was to use 'putExtra()' on the intent, but that doesn't really suit the use case as the delegate I'd like to put there really is a View and not a serializable data object.

Are there any ways for me to handle this internally? I am aware of the 'onActivityResult()' function (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), but that would mean that the third party developer using my module would need to handle this, something that needs to be avoided for obvious reasons.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT: FINAL SOLUTION**
In the end I've changed the module from View to Fragment, which now works much better with handling "child" activities and such. When starting an Activity from a Fragment, the 'onActivityResult' function works beautifully to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: "so that the module will get notified when the settings have been changed" -- why not use [an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)?

Comment: How would I register that listener then? I mean the PreferencesActivity would get started from a view, not an activity.

Comment: Having a view launch an activity is a separation-of-concerns design flaw, IMHO. That being said, there is nothing stopping a `View` from getting access to the `SharedPreferences` and calling `setOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` before launching that `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: I agree, activities should launch activities, but given that this module needs to hide as much of the implementation as possible, I don't see any other way to handle this. The module will be a drop in component just like a Button or TextView that you can add to any activity with the small difference that this View is far more complex and includes other activities that allow the end user to configure the module. In case you have a better solution as to how to accomplish this, please don't hesitate to elaborate!

Comment: "and includes other activities that allow the end user to configure the module" -- the developer of the app can hook up to those other activities as that developer sees fit (action bar items, navigation drawer, integration in the hosting app's own preference screens, etc.).

Comment: Sure, that would be possible and a more "open" solution as well. Unfortunately, that's not what the customer requested. He wants an encapsulated module that works "as is". On iOS that requirement is quite simple to achieve without breaking any Cocoa design guidelines, on Android I feel that this somehow bending the framework here and there. Not feeling that comfortable with this either, especially since I'm not entirely settled on using a View vs. Fragment, but that's a different story.

Comment: Unless the only developers using this module are the customer's own employees, the customer really should be thinking about what the developers using the module will want.

Comment: Developers are the customer's only, and for me, the requirement is absolutely comprehensible. Still, I highly appreciate your input and will certainly consider the route you suggested for future modules that can be more open to the developer using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start an `Activity` from a `View` using its `Context` as in:

```
@Override
public void onClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ConfigActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("testVar", "testtest");
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

You could use the [`onWindowVisibilityChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowVisibilityChanged(int)) method to read the configuration that would be set in the `ConfigActivity` to make your `View` change its behavior.

Comment: Using getContext() in the View to start the new activity works nicely. Thanks for that. However, I can't use putExtra as I'd need to pass an Interface the View implements to it.

Comment: Why would you need to pass the `View` itself?

Comment: Well, I want a callback to the View. Are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: If you plan to update the `View` on changes in the Activity, you can use the `onWindowVisibilityChanged()` method to update the `View` when back from the `Activity` (using SharedPreferences for exemple, as you may save configuration in that `ConfigActivity`)

Comment: GIven that I know when the config has been opened, the window visibility should do the trick. Thanks mate.